# MapR on Ubuntu 12.0.4 - Disk setup on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, mapr

I see these steps in seting up the disk for MapR installation at [link](http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR12/Setting+Up+Disks+for+MapR)

> To determine if a disk or partition is ready for use by MapR:
>
> Run the command sudo lsof  to determine whether any processes are
> already using the disk or partition.
>
> There should be no output when running sudo fuser , indicating there is no > process accessing the specific disk or partition.
>
> The disk or partition should not be mounted, as checked via the output of the mount ?command.
>
> The disk or partition should not have an entry in the /etc/fstab file.
>
> The disk or partition should be accessible to standard Linux tools such as
> mkfs. You should be able to successfully format the partition using a
> command like sudo mkfs.ext3  as this is similar to the
> operations MapR performs during installation. If mkfs fails to access
> and format the partition, then it is highly likely MapR will encounter
> the same problem.

I have issues in acheiving this on amazon EC2 instance.
Steps that i have tried

> 1. I have created a large EC2 instance.
> 2. Created the snapsot of that volume associated with that instance
> 3. Created a new volume with 500 GB from the snapshot created above

I am not sure, how to unmount this new volume and make it available for MapR. I also see an entry in /etc/fstab for this new volume.

Can some one give a step-by-step approach to create a disk or partition which satisfies the above mentioned criteria for MapR?

Answer (score 0):

MapR runs on raw disks, eg, directly on /dev/sdb.  Use the disksetup command to add disks to MapR. See http://mapr.com/doc/display/MapR/disksetup for information on how to use.